# Django requirements.txt pip for mdbtools

Tags: django, installation, requirements, mdbtools

I'm trying to use mdbtools in a django app I have. I've included the following two lines in my requirements.txt file:

```
mdbtools-dev
mdbtools
```

but am running into some errors:

```
....
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stripe in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
Downloading/unpacking mdbtools-dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mdbtools-dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
No distributions at all found for mdbtools-dev (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
```

!  Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

I sudo apt-get install both mdbtools and mdbtools-dev without a problem. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

`requirements.txt` file is not for general system requirements - it is only for Python libraries that are necessary for your application.

Since there is no Python package called `mdbtools`, you are getting that error.

Comment: That makes sense -- thank you. Do you know how I ensure that mdbtools is installed as I need it to be? I'm using Heroku

Comment: You can't, as Heroku provides a [read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). You need to use a supported database, like [Heroku postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-postgres).